# Array vs. Dictionary - which is more expensive to initialize?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, performance, dictionary

Regarding iOS Swift -

Which is heavier / more expensive to initialize - an Array or Dictionary?

This small detail matters when you're dealing w/ large data sets & in very large corporations that may have millions of items in an array, dictionary or some other data structure that may be based off these.

-

### TEST RESULTS:

[image]
- The test results above show how much time it took to initialize 1,000,000 empty Arrays, Dictionaries, & I decided to throw Set in there too.

-

### **ANSWER:** ARRAY'S LIGHTER THAN SET & DICTIONARY.

-

BELOW IS THE REMAINDER OF THE DESCRIPTION THAT WAS WRITTEN WHEN I ORIGINALLY WROTE THIS QUESTION:

In Java, hash map is built on top of their array.

Apple says the Dictionary is "a type" of hash table and
"similar data types are known as hashes or associated arrays."

Apple clearly says a dictionary is not a hash map / hash table, nor an associated array. It is a type of those & similar.

A "a type of" doesn't mean it's some revolutionary new standard that is completely different from the other similar types, but Apple is clear that they are not the same. It may differ in how they choose to calculate the hash, how they store elements that collide at the same array index, etc.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary?fbclid=IwAR30CezlfvqpRdqjn5cnJlQmUc5Ys70GwJX7mYOKgHyDcd_kKuURgdoYnCY

Comment: A good way to find out is to profile it yourself. You could test a `measureBlock` or simply have a loop and check the time before and after. That way you can be 100% assured.

Comment: Also, this is an implementation detail and, regardless of how it performs now, if the documentation doesn't provide any guarantees, it might perform completely differently tomorrow. Thus, it might not be a good idea to base anything on these findings.

Comment: Does it matter, either you need an array or you need a dictionary?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson - Yes it can matter significantly. Also, sometimes you can get a job done w/ a dictionary that you can also do w/ an array. If you know one is lighter then it makes sense to choose the lighter data structure.

Comment: About the documentation - they're only saying that it's a hash table like any other hash table in other languages, which might be known as "hashes" or "associated arrays". They're not giving any details about how exactly it's implemented.

Comment: @rid - Their wording says it is "like" a hash table. It does not say that it is a hash table. It also says it's "similar" to hashes or associated arrays.

Comment: I find it hard to believe a dictionary could be faster than an array if you only want to use the dictionary as an array but why don't you create a test bench and test the performance for your use case.

Comment: @japsoccer I'd say your design is really wrong if you use array vs dictionary based on their initialization speed. Initialization is insignificant, you did it *once*. Dictionary insert cost slightly more due to hashing, but retrieving is much faster, assuming you rely on their key (vs array where you'd need to reiterate the whole component to find the correct key). But if you have no need for key, then just use array.

Comment: @japsoccer, hmm, I don't think they're saying "like". They're saying "a type of hash table", meaning some form of hash table, not "like a hash table", meaning something that looks like a hash table but is not.

Comment: @Martheen How is initialization insignificant?  Initialization can be O(n)

Comment: @Martheen - Dictionary insert is cheaper than Array. Accessing in both is the same if you are using the key (for dictionary) & index (for Array).

Comment: @japsoccer, just test. That way you'll know. But do keep in mind that everything can change at any time, since they don't specify performance explicitly.

Comment: @rid - right, that's what I wrote in the question. Apple clearly says a dictionary is not a hash map / hash table, nor an associated array. It is a type of those & similar. That means there are differences.

Comment: @japsoccer we seem to have a different interpretation of what they mean with those words. You could just read Swift's source code at https://github.com/apple/swift to find out exactly how they implement it today.

Comment: @japsoccer see https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Dictionary.swift, especially the comment "Native storage is a hash table with open addressing and linear probing". They also detail exactly how the dictionary works.

Comment: @japsoccer If you're using Arrays and instead keep inserting into it to the point it become noticeable on the performance, then you're doing it wrong. Show us your actual scenario. Arrays and Dictionary are made for different use case. It's like nagging whether you're better off using a race car vs a truck.

Comment: @Martheen - I am very aware of the space complexities & asymptotic notations for the Array & Dictionary & their operations' time complexities. This is not nagging - when you're dealing w/ large data sets this is important. Little things like this matter in very large corporations that may have millions of items in an array, dictionary or some other data structure that may be based off these.

Comment: @japsoccer another idea, if performance is critical, would be to implement this in C and expose your C API to Swift. The Swift-C bridging is pretty user friendly.

Comment: @rid - thank you rid. I appreciate that

Comment: @japsoccer You use those words but your very next sentences shows you haven't actually understood them. If you have millions of data items you'd need to access based on a *key*, I repeat, *key*, not *index*, then you need dictionary. Otherwise you use array if you need index, or Sets if you don't need index at all.

Comment: @Martheen - I said - "Accessing in both is the same if you are using the key (for dictionary) & index (for Array)"

Comment: @japsoccer The scenarios for key and index are very different. You *will* need keys when dealing with say, millions of customers, but you only need indexes when dealing with interchangeable items, like stocks of identical book copies. The circumstance where you need one vs the other is *very* different, to the point when you actually understand why you need one vs the other, it's pointless to talk about "initialization speed"

Comment: @Martheen - I asked a specific question.

Comment: @Martheen - I'm not interested in discussing when it's important to use an array vs. using a dictionary due to importance of the key, which might make more sense than an array's index, given x, y, & z use cases. Please stay on topic.

Answer (score -1):

I put everything in a `measure` block.

[image]